# connecting to MariaDB using PyMSQL in raspbian

Tags: python, flask, mariadb, raspberry-pi3, pymysql

i am trying to connect to mariaDB in my flask project using pymysql.

this is my code :

```
from flask import Flask
import pymysql.cursors

app = Flask(__name__)

try:
    connection = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1',
                                 user='root',
                                 password='password',
                                 db='thesis',
                                 charset='utf8mb4',
                                 cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
    print('all fine')
```

and i got the following error when i run this on raspberry pi :

```
  File "app.py", line 12, in <module>
    cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pymysql/__init__.py", line 94, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 327, in __init__
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 597, in connect
    self._get_server_information()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 966, in _get_server_information
    packet = self._read_packet()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pymysql/connections.py", line 670, in _read_packet
    % (packet_number, self._next_seq_id))
pymysql.err.InternalError: Packet sequence number wrong - got 1 expected 0
```

and i don't know what to do everything works fine in my laptop but in raspberry pi everything is like this !

anyway my pymysql version is 0.9.2.

Comment: the problme was for *127.0.0.1* . mysql was not listening on localhost.